# JQuery How to set attribute of element using other attribute of the same element

Tags: jquery

I want to set title text of a link calling a function which receives as parameter the id of the element and outputs the text.

something like

```
$(a).attr('title', function() {return $(this).id + "foo"});
```

but a construct like this doesn't exist as far I know. What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Just a note that `prop` is recommended over `attr` in most cases as of jQuery 1.7+

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$(this).attr('id')` or `this.id`. Do **not** mix them.

```
$(a).attr('title', function() {return $(this).attr('id') + "foo"});
$(a).attr('title', function() {return this.id + "foo"});        // <-- Preferred
//^ Is this a a variable? If not, you have to quote it: $("a").attr( ... );
```

Comment: +1. Though there's never really any reason to use `$(this).attr('id')` - it's longer to type and results in unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title', this.id + ' foo');
});
```

References: [jQuery `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = $(this).attr('id') ; //capture the caller 
$(a).attr('title',id + 'foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Maybe?